# What is the procedure to climb and level off using a Bendix/King KAP140 autopilot?

Tags: autopilot, altitude

What's the procedure to use the Bendix/King KAP 140 autopilot in the Cessna piston singles to climb to a certain altitude and then capture it and level off?

Comment: Are you asking how to work the autopilot? Or is there anything in particular that makes it different for a cessna single?

Comment: The KAP 140 was what I was looking for. I just forgot the model number. I'll edit it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the KAP140 two-axis autopilot with altitude preselect supports capturing a preselected altitude (which is the one installed in the Cessna 172 before the introduction of the Garmin GFC700)

Preselect the desired altitude using the altitude preselect knob, switch to VS mode, select the desired VS and the AP will switch to altitude hold mode when the preselected altitude is reached.

Taken from [the manual](http://www.bendixking.com/HWL/media/PDF/PilotsGuides/PG-KAP140.pdf).